# Matlab indexing and replacing in python

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

In matalb we can have a vector as a=[1,3,4] and use it to access and replace elements of another vector or matrix, like this.

```
a=[1,2,4];
b=[1,2,3,4];
b(a)=1
```

so b would be [1,1,3,1]

Is there anyway to do  this in python?

I know I can do stuff like this:

```
a=[1,2,4]
b=list(range(1,10))

[b[x] for x in a]
```

but it doesn't alow me to replace the values, for example.

Comment: take a look at numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy has similar functionality. However, keep in mind that Numpy indexing starts at 0. not at 1:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b[a - 1] = 1
print(b)
#[1 1 3 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use logical indexing in python:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,1,0])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])

b[a==True]=1
#[1 1 1 8]
```